# minSdkVersion is 26 in config.xml, but google play store showing 5.1 instead of 8.0

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, google-play, google-play-console

Good day,

I have a cordova android mobile app, the minSdkVersion is 26 in my config.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" />
```

As my understanding, sdkversion = 26 should equal to android 8.0:

[image]

However, in google play store, it showing 5.1 and above:

[image]

May I know where is this 5.1 come from? and how can I control it?

Comment: The `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" />` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file will be overridden by the value of `android.minSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` file of the app module.

Comment: @SovathnaHong , Ya, i found that the mfp push plugin build.gradle sdk version will override it. My workaround is manually update the build.gradle file to fix this. Thanks for the info.